# use res.json() to return two different sachems in http get?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I created two schemes: Sales and Abc

I want to send a response that will contain both schemas documents :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Sales.find(function (err, sales) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(sales);
    });
    Abc.find(function (err, abc) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(abc);
    });
});
```

I know that I cant use res.json() more than once 
so what is the proper way to do it?

And what do I need to change in client-side (**api.service.ts** file) to receive those 2 schemas from the same apiUrl path?

```
  getSales(): Observable<Sales[]> {
    return this.http.get<Sales[]>(`${apiUrl}`)
      .pipe(
        tap(sales => console.log('fetched sales')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getSales', []))
      );
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by sending an object in res.json() like below.

res.json({

```
 sales = sales,
 abc = abc
```

})

Comment: ok thanks, but how to change the Observable type? (Observable<Sales[]>)